# Simple CSS Layout

Tags: css, layout, height

I need to find a cross browser way of having two divs contained in a parent div where the first child has a fixed height and the second flows down to be contained in the parent.

`<div id="parent"><div id="header"></div><div id="body"></div></div>`

```
     height: 500px
 _____________________
|  _________________  |
| |  height: 20px   | |
| |_________________| |
|  _________________  |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |  height: 100%   | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |_________________| |
|_____________________|
```

So the parent has a fixed height of 500px, the header div has a fixed height of 20px but the body div's height must flow down to fit inside the parent. Giving it a height of 100% overflows it's height by 20px because height:100% uses the parents height not taking into account the children. I saw a solution using position absolute but this does not work on IE7 or 6. Is there a cross browser solution for this as it is a relatively simple layout?

**Edit:** Forgot to mention that the parent will be resizable so will not always be 500px. Using jquery resizable, the parent dimensions could be anything and will change often.

**Edit 2:** I wish I could credit multiple people for this solution as I took advice from everyone. Basically I gave `#body` a height of 480px and used the alsoResize option in resizable to resize the parent and the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.parent  { height : auto; }
.child1  { height : 20px;  }
.child2  { height : 480px;  }
```

Instead of setting the size of the parent dynamically, control child2's height.

Hope that is what your asking for.

**Edit: Edited as per your update!**

Comment: That won't do it; `child2`'s `height: auto` means it will be sized to the height of its contents.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the height of outer container, and the one of height of the divisions inside, you can know the height of the remaining div I think.

try something like this `height: 480px;`. Keep it simple and easy

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't as simple a problem as you think it ought to be.  You can use some javascript to change the height of `body` based on `parent`'s computed height.

But the simplest thing may be to just set `body`s height to 100%, and set `overflow: hidden` on the `parent` div.

This way the body will have a height equal to the parent, but the bottom 20px will just be clipped.  This may or may not be acceptable, depending on what you're doing with the `body`, and whether its content will potentially reach the bottom.

---

Another approach would be to use:

```
#header { height: 20px; }
#body { height: 480px; }
#parent { height: auto; }
```

and have `body` be the one that gets resized by the script, rather than `parent`.  `parent` will automatically be sized to surround the total height of `header` + `body`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for a page where parent has a dynamic height:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
            }

            #parent {
                height: 80%;
                width: 500px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }

            #header {
                height: 120px;
                background-color: #456;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 101;
            }

            #body {
                height: 100%;
                margin-top: -120px;
                background-color: #789;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 100;
            }

            #spacer {
                height: 120px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="parent">
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div id="body">
                <div id="spacer"><!-- Padding will just increase body's height. --></div>
                Body content.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If #parent always have 500px height, and #header, why not just putting 480px (1) to #body?

(1) Of course you have to discount any vertical margin or padding.

PS: Testing in IE6 may not be worth the time nowadays

Comment: IE6 is a requirement for many organizations since there are still plenty of IE6 users out there.

Comment: That's true unluckly, but for the standard non-enterprise website you can forget about ie6, even google is doing this

Comment: Unfortunately, the site's audience will include office workers most likely forced to use IE6 or 7. Portability is essential :(